# How to express the difference between dating and a stable relationships?

Tags: vocabulaire

Je sais qu'on peut utiliser *sortir ensemble*, mais j'ai l'impression que ça implique plutôt une relation moins sérieuse. (Comme *dating* en anglais).

Y a-t-il un mot pour exprimer une relation sérieuse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Être ensemble » peut être utilisé pour décrire une relation en général plus sérieuse que « sortir ensemble ».

Comment: Ahhh effectivement. Je n'y avait pas pensé.

Answer (score 3):

Je propose comme alternative tout bêtement « être en couple », qui a un sens légèrement plus fort.

Answer (score 2):

Au Québec, une relation plus sérieuse emploi généralement le terme de « conjoints ». Étant donné l'existence du terme légal *conjoints de faits*, le mot « conjoints », dans le langage familier, n'implique pas nécessairement le mariage, mais est certainement plus sérieux qu'*une blonde / un chum*.